# Как задать value для angular application в контейнере script внутри html?

Tags: angularjs

Angular приложение запускается через bootstrap:

```
  <script>
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('div_app'), ['demo']);
  </script>
```

Код контроллера должен находиться в отдельном js файле.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'val', function($scope, val) {
  $scope.new = 'New ' + val;
}]);
```

Нужно установить value для приложения в контейнере script внутри html. Что-то вроде:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []).value("val", "World");
```

[Plunker примера](https://plnkr.co/edit/jNR48S?p=preview)

Comment: эм, в планкере вроде все работает, можете конкретизировать вопрос?

Comment: В планкере value задается в js файле, а нужно в script-контейнере внутри html

Comment: так? [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/w77ZZ0ruy4MQc8I4WPik?p=preview)

Comment: Так .   Спасибо .

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, добавил, но мне кажется тут больше подходит под причину: не воспроизводится или опечатка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не мешает вынести создание модуля в отдельный скрипт

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('demo', []).value("val", "World");
</script>
```

Главное подключить его раньше файла с основным кодом.
Пример на [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/w77ZZ0ruy4MQc8I4WPik?p=preview)

Кроме того, можно не сохранять полученный модуль в переменную.

```
<script>
    angular.module('demo', []).value("val", "World");
</script>
```

В этом случае в основном скрипте нужно добавить строку получения модуля

```
app = angular.module('demo'); //обратите внимание на отсутствие списка зависимостей.
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'val', function($scope, val) {
  $scope.new = 'New ' + val;
}]);
```